# How to convert between time zones in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, timezone

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2 and I wanted to know how we can convert CST time to IST time. I already have CST time in my dtDate column and want to convert it to IST format. Can somebody please help me to get it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will assume you mean "Cental Standard Time" and "India Standard Time" since "CST" and "IST" can mean a few different things. If this is wrong, just substitute the correct offsets for your timezones into something like this:

```
select cast(switchoffset(todatetimeoffset(dtDate, '-06:00'), '+05:30') as datetime)
```

Here are the steps:

- [Convert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630335.aspx) our datetime to a [datetimeoffset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630289.aspx), which is a time zone aware datatype.
- [Switch the offset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677244.aspx) to a new time zone.
- Cast to a datetime (optional, but that seems to be what you want).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is a perfect answer.  I don't know about the timezones you mention, but it doesn't help me.

I am based in the UK, within a US company and I produce reports in ET time zone.  The system I extract data from holds all its dates in UTC.  The server I run the reports on is hosted in NY and the times are ET.

I am reporting historical data and need to convert dates on tables into ET dates.  I have been subtracting the difference between GETDATE() and GETUTCDATE() but I realise that I am getting that difference between those dates now, today.  The dates I am converting are historical and, to cut a long story short, there are 4 hours difference between ET and UTC for 8 months of the year and 5 hours for the other 4 months.

If you are converting dates for zones with daylight savings you need a more sophisticated solution

Comment: Hello Helen, welcome to StackOverflow. If an answer does not help your use case, please submit another question rather than asking in an answer.