# How to get time converted to IST in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, timezone

I have the Data in a an SQL DataTable by the name `DPSDateTime`. Shown below are the data columns with values:

```
crea_date                      Disp_Day             Disp_Time      State        TimeZone
11/13/14 5:56 PM    Thursday, December 18, 2014     19:00:09        IL  (GMT-06:00) Central Time (US & Canada)
11/24/14 11:17 AM   Wednesday, December 24, 2014    10:27:44    WA  (GMT-07:00) Mountain Time (US & Canada)
12/12/14 1:19 PM    Wednesday, December 24, 2014    19:24:33    WI  (GMT-06:00) Central Time (US & Canada)
12/13/14 12:05 PM   Thursday, December 25, 2014     12:36:27        CA  (GMT-05:00) Eastern Time (US & Canada)
12/17/14 11:33 AM   Monday, December 29, 2014       08:16:35        OR  (GMT-08:00) Pacific Time (US & Canada); Tijuana
12/17/14 2:03 PM    Thursday, December 25, 2014     13:00:21        CA  (GMT-05:00) Eastern Time (US & Canada)
12/18/14 11:05 AM   Thursday, December 25, 2014     15:06:44        TX  (GMT-06:00) Central Time (US & Canada)
12/18/14 9:16 AM    Thursday, December 25, 2014     07:59:16        WA  (GMT-07:00) Mountain Time (US & Canada)
12/18/14 5:27 PM    Saturday, December 20, 2014     11:23:04        WA  (GMT-07:00) Mountain Time (US & Canada)
12/19/14 10:07 AM   Monday, December 29, 2014       06:55:31        LA  (GMT-06:00) Central Time (US & Canada)
12/22/14 4:44 PM    Monday, December 22, 2014       18:20:27        NJ  (GMT-05:00) Eastern Time (US & Canada)
12/22/14 4:53 PM    Monday, December 22, 2014       17:47:08        OK  (GMT-06:00) Central Time (US & Canada)
12/23/14 1:31 PM    Friday, December 26, 2014       18:37:00        NH  (GMT-05:00) Eastern Time (US & Canada)
12/23/14 3:18 PM    Tuesday, December 23, 2014      21:25:26        MS  (GMT-06:00) Central Time (US & Canada)
12/23/14 4:37 PM    Friday, December 26, 2014       15:28:04        MD  (GMT-05:00) Eastern Time (US & Canada)
```

In the above table `crae_date` column has DateTime Value and State and TimeZone Columns show the respective Sate and TimeZones for the value in `crea_date` column.

I want to add another Column by the Name `ISTTime`. I want to show the value of the `crea_date` column converted into IST (Indian Standard Time) in this column.

I have checked the solution provided in "[How to convert between time zones in SQL Server 2008?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14478332/how-to-convert-between-time-zones-in-sql-server-2008)". This gives the method to convert a single value to another TimeZone. I need the entire column with different TimeZones converted to IST.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: May I ask why? Shouldn't UI be handling locale?

Comment: @danish, Thank you for reviewing my post. Sir, I am not aware how to change the locale in UI (You mean "User Interface" by UI, if I am correct?). I am new to asp .NET. 
Thanks.

Comment: Yes, user interface should probably take care of that. I would recommend saving dates in UTC or any other format you wish and then control on your screen should format it accordingly.

Comment: @danish, Thank you for your valuable input. I have decided to proceed with your Idea of solving this in User Interface. Kindly post here the Sample Code for the Data to be displayed in the GridView Control. I am using VB .NET as Programming Language and it is an ASP .NET WebPage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this query for getting time converted to IST :

```
SELECT SWITCHOFFSET(SYSDATETIMEOFFSET(), '+05:30')
```

Comment: The simple and best solution I could see on internet. Thanks @irshad